# cannot enable remote access on Windows 11

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11

so I don't know how it happened but suddenly I cannot connect to my work laptop with Windows 11 via RDP. The settings is off and when I toggle it, it asks me for credentials, then I click confirm but it doesn't change to on and stays off!
[image]

Comment: In Windows 11 RDP, pull down the options and make sure it is set to save credentials.  Also run DISM / SFC and restart.   ...   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Please give more details about the RDP setting on your work laptop. Are you sure that the admin in your work domain hasn't blocked RDP?

Comment: I am not sure if admin blocked it. How can I find out? If it's the case then wouldn't this settings be just greyed out with message "this setting is set by the administrator of your company"? As it is with some other settings. I guess I would be able to find this group policy somewhere in rsop.msc if it was applied, but where?...

Comment: You should probably start by asking your work's technical staff.

Answer (score -1):

Windows will toggle this off/on based on your Network Profile, which could be the cause. From PowerShell, check your network for "Public" and try toggling to "Private":

1. `Get-NetConnectionProfile`
2. `Set-NetConnectionProfile -Name <Name_From_Step_1> -NetworkCategory Private`

For example:

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).